# Extra space on the first line after wrapfigure and pspicture caption not centered

Tags: pstricks, wrapfigure

Two questions about below MWE from a pstricks newbie:

1. Why is there an extra space between the picture and the first `\sin\alpha` formula?
2. Why is the caption of the `pspicture` stuck to the right?

(Adding `\par` as commented out did not work.)

Appreciate your help!

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

% Compile sequence: F2, F4, F8, F7
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
\pspicture(0,0)(5.5,4.5)
\pstTriangle(0,0){B}(4,3){A}(4,0){C}
\pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{A}{$\alpha$}
\pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{C}{$\beta$}
\pstMarkAngle{A}{C}{B}{$\gamma$}
\pcline[linestyle=none](0,0)(4,3)
\naput[nrot=:U]{c}
\pcline[linestyle=none](0,0)(4,0)
\tbput{a}
\pcline[linestyle=none](4,0)(4,3)
\trput{b}
\endpspicture
\captionof{figure}{Straight triangle}
\end{wrapfigure}
%\par
\[\sin\alpha=\frac{b}{c}\]
\[\cos\alpha=\frac{a}{c}\]
\[\tan\alpha=\frac{b}{a}\]
\[\sin\beta=\frac{a}{c}\]
\[\cos\beta=\frac{b}{c}\]
\[\tan\beta=\frac{a}{b}\]
\end{document}
```

And if I replaced the last lines after `%\par` with the following, then the first line of 3 formulas would still be pushed far to the right, the second line would overlap the picture, and lorem ipsum would simply ignore the picture on the first page, but wrap a non-existing picture on the following pages. (`\usepackage{lipsum}` required.)

```
\[\sin\alpha=\frac{b}{c}\quad\cos\alpha=\frac{a}{c}\quad\tan\alpha=\frac{b}{a}\]
\[\sin\beta=\frac{a}{c}\quad\cos\beta=\frac{b}{c}\quad\tan\beta=\frac{a}{b}\]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This would render lorem ipsum correctly, but the formulas would have a new line after `sin a =`:

```
$\sin\alpha=\frac{b}{c}\quad\cos\alpha=\frac{a}{c}\quad\tan\alpha=\frac{b}{a}$\\
$\sin\beta=\frac{a}{c}\quad\cos\beta=\frac{b}{c}\quad\tan\beta=\frac{a}{b}$\\
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want `wrapfigure`, but the `columns` environment of `beamer`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
% Compile sequence: F2, F4, F8, F7
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\pspicture(0,0)(5.5,4.5)
\pstTriangle(0,0){B}(4,3){A}(4,0){C}
\pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{A}{$\alpha$}
\pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{C}{$\beta$}
\pstMarkAngle{A}{C}{B}{$\gamma$}
\pcline[linestyle=none](0,0)(4,3)
\naput[nrot=:U]{c}
\pcline[linestyle=none](0,0)(4,0)
\tbput{a}
\pcline[linestyle=none](4,0)(4,3)
\trput{b}
\endpspicture
\captionof{figure}{Straight triangle}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\sin\alpha&=\frac{b}{c}\\
\cos\alpha&=\frac{a}{c}\\
\tan\alpha&=\frac{b}{a}\\
\sin\beta&=\frac{a}{c}\\
\cos\beta&=\frac{b}{c}\\
\tan\beta&=\frac{a}{b}
\end{align*}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Adjust the relative positioning.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I wanted exactly wrapfigure, as the formulas that will follow, should start from the left side of the page. The posters do not necessarily have to be in landscape (which I have not dealt with yet, but it is unwanted) and formulas will need to flow around the pictures.

Comment: @ajeh No, you don't want `wrapfigure` anyway.

Comment: Does not have to be beamer.

Answer (score 3):

it makes no real sense to use `wrapfig` here. Using two minipages makes more sense. However, if you absolutely want to use `wrapfig` then use only *one* `\[...\]`. Otherwise the first one is set right to the figure and the others which are always own paragraphs are centered to the whole line.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

% Compile sequence: F2, F4, F8, F7
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
\pspicture(0,0)(5.5,4.5)
\pstTriangle(0,0){B}(4,3){A}(4,0){C}
\pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{A}{$\alpha$}
\pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{C}{$\beta$}
\pstMarkAngle{A}{C}{B}{$\gamma$}
\pcline[linestyle=none](0,0)(4,3)
\naput[nrot=:U]{c}
\pcline[linestyle=none](0,0)(4,0)
\tbput{a}
\pcline[linestyle=none](4,0)(4,3)
\trput{b}
\endpspicture
\captionof{figure}{Straight triangle}
\end{wrapfigure}
\arraycolsep=1.4pt\def\arraystretch{1.75}
\[\begin{array}[t]{rl}
\sin\alpha=\dfrac{b}{c}\\
\cos\alpha=\dfrac{a}{c}\\
\tan\alpha=\dfrac{b}{a}\\
\sin\beta=\dfrac{a}{c}\\
\cos\beta=\dfrac{b}{c}\\
\tan\beta=\dfrac{a}{b}
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like egreg, you are looking at MWE and assuming that's it. This is MWE. In real document I will need text including formulas flow around the pictures scattered across the pages. This has to be wrapped. This is a requrement. Guess I will have to edit MWE to include lots of static text to make the point obvious.